# retrieving text file from a Raspberry pi with Filezilla is one continuous string

Tags: text, character-encoding, raspberry-pi, filezilla

I'm trying to grab a text logfile file created by a python program from a raspberry that is in the format:

datathing

datathing

datathing

etc

but when I retrieve it with Filezilla it looks like:
datathingdatathingdatathingdatathing

is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Try setting ASCII mode rather than BINARY.

Comment: Probably has something to do with CR vs LF

Comment: I think `Wordpad` understands Linux line-endings, but `Notepad` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are taking this file into windows and viewing it in notepad?  Unix systems, as in the rapsberry pi, use '\n' as a line terminator whereas Windows systems use '\r\n'.  You'll need to use ASCII transfer method as opposed to binary.